# How could I change a list of URLs to HTML links?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, notepad++

I have a list of URLs that I'd like to convert into HTML.

Here's an example:

```
http://blah.com
https://abc.com
http://123.com
```

to

```
<a href="http://blah.com">http://blah.com</a>
<a href="https://abc.com">https://abc.com</a>
<a href="http://123.com">http://123.com</a>
```

I know that I can use an online converter, but I also want to learn how to make the most out of Notepad++ and Sublime Text. I'm not even sure if I can do that or if there's an easier way (without using a converter).

Also, any easy to learn regex resources? I've checked out RegexPal and RegExr but didn't find them helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Does the file contains only urls? (without other contents)

Comment: Notepad++ and SublimeText2 uses Boost library, which you can go directly to the library for documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search -> replace

replace: `(https?://\S*)`
with: `<a href="\1">\1</a>`

search method: regexp

Comment: No need to use `[`, `]`.

Comment: Thanks, the first part worked but the second part didn't. It would replace the lines with "<a href="$0">$0</a>"

Comment: @userrandomnums: works for me in notepad++ 6.5.3, if `$0` doesn't work in some other editor, surround your expression in parentheses and try `\1`